# How can credit cards be encrypted and still be recalled later?

Tags: encryption

Many merchants offer to save credit card info in an encrypted form for faster checkouts from their store in the future. How is it that merchants can store this information in an encrypted format and still be able to decrypt it to plain text later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing encryption with hashing because hashing is one way whereas encryption is two-way providing you have the proper key to decrypt whatever is encrypted.

Short answer is: they are storing the key somewhere (in a hopefully secure location). Whenever they need to decrypt the credit card number they hand the encrypted data to a module that looks up the key, decrypts the card number, and returns the card number to the payment system.

Comment: Hopefully they are padding the data with some noise as credit card data is short and the format is well known. It is too much to hope for some type of CBC CFB or IV as this would impeed parallel decryption of individual card info.

Comment: @the.josh as a credit card number is 16 digits long, lets Assume that they were using a block cipher like AES and that the credit card is just 8 bit (1 byte) ansi characters. That's 16*8 == 128 bits which happens to be the block size of AES in the first place so nomatter the block cipher mode it's going to end up a single block.

Comment: so, the only hope is to get doing IV's right.